# Can I update a variable from a child component to a parent component?

Tags: reactjs, properties, components, store

Let's say I have a component **Child** nested in a component **Parent**.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [myParentData,setParentMyData] = useState({
    foo:'bar',
    hello:'world'
  });
  return (
    <Child
    data={myData}
    />
  )
}

const Child = (props) => {
  const [myChildData,setMyChildData] = useState(props.data);
}
```

I have a "theorical" question.

Javascript variables are references...
So, if I update the data state with *setMyChildData* within the **Child** component,
will those changes be reflected in *myParentData* (**Parent** component) too?

Or am I forced to use a store+reducers to achieve that ?

Thanks !

Comment: A well written answers here:
By 'Yasin Br' -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69595704/updating-a-react-state-from-child-component-function/69595728#69595728

Comment: A well written answers here:
By 'Yasin Br' -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69595704/updating-a-react-state-from-child-component-function/69595728#69595728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are setting the data from the parent inside the initial state of child and then changing the child state you are changing the child only now because its totally new variable, a way to change parent state you can do like this:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [myParentData, setParentMyData] = React.useState({
    foo: "bar",
    hello: "world"
  });
  return <Child data={myParentData} updateParentData={setParentMyData} />;
};

const Child = (props) => {
  const [myChildData, setMyChildData] = React.useState(props.data);

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        props.updateParentData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, hello: "bye" }))
      }}
    >
      Change Parent Data
    </button>
  );
};
```

no need to keep separate states in both child and parent if they are the same.

the thing that you are doing is like:

```
const parent = {foo:'bar',hello:'world'}
const child = {...parent}

child.foo = 'zoo'
```

it will not affect the parent anymore since its new object , same is happening above in component state after you initialize with parent data in new state (of child)

Answer (score 0):

no, when you change the state myChildData you don't change the father data that you send by props.
You can also send the setParentMyData function and by this function (without a new state in the son) you will change the father's data